# c array concatenation problem

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to concatenate an array with the array from argv (I forgot the formal name for that, input array? parameter array?)

anyway, I initalize the original array, then I use `memcpy` to copy the two arrays into the new array.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *args1[] = {"foo","bar"};
  char **args = (char**) calloc(argc, sizeof(char*));
  memcpy(args, args1, sizeof(char*) * 2);
  memcpy(args + sizeof(char*) * 2, argv+1, sizeof(char*) * (argc-1));
```

but when I run this

```
  printf("%s %s %s\n", args[0], args[1], args[2]);
```

and then run

> ./test baz

I get a result of

> foo bar (null)

So I'm trying to figure out where my second memcpy screwed up, but I can't find it. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems in this code.

**Problem #1**

```
calloc(argc, sizeof(char*))
```

should be

```
calloc(argc + 2, sizeof(char*))
```

**Problem #2**

You are confusing pointer arithmetic. This part

```
args + sizeof(char*) * 2
```

should simply be

```
args + 2
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
&args[2]
```

Either way, don't multiply the offset by the size of the type. The compiler does that automatically.

Comment: sigh. I know my pointer arithmetic, so it was silly of me to make that kind of error and not notice it. That's the last time I take pointers from rosettacode